# XPages. compositeData in nested custom controls

Tags: xpages, custom-controls

I have a hierarchy of nested custom controls. Some of them have custom properties. One CC has property 'refreshId' which is set from parent cc:

```
<xc:SomeCC refreshId="componentId"><xc:SomeCC>
```

On my custom control (SomeCC) I retrieve that property:

```
<xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1"
    value="#{javascript:compositeData.refreshId}">
</xp:text>
```

And...it is null. There is no such property. But if I do

```
<xp:button value="Label" id="button1">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
        refreshMode="partial" refreshId="computedField1">
        <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:println(compositeData.refreshId)}]]></xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
```

on same cc (SomeCC) - on console I see

> componentId

What am I doing wrong or missunderstand?

Comment: This code is fine. Just put it in a new XPage + SomeCC and it will work. So, there is something else broken...

Comment: @KnutHerrmann Thanks! Could the problem be, that parent cc is added to XPages via includePage control with a computed page name?... anyway I'll check that out...